# Does JavaScript have class relationships?

Tags: java, javascript, class, object

In school, I have been taught that Java has class relationships (is-a and has-a).  I am required to show both types of relationships for a project however I have decided to use Java to parse data I have been given and then use a webpage to display a visualization of said data.  So can I show is-a and has-a relationships in JavaScript?

--edit--

I already have a Java program that creates an object out of the data I have been given. I will have the program open a webpage when it is done that will visualize the data.  That is where the JavaScript comes in.  Does that make sense? Or am I doing this the really hard way?

Comment: Java != JavaScript. They're totally not related (except the name). So which one really?

Comment: You can show anything you want using basically anything you want.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to really have anything to do with JavaScript. Can you describe your problem in more detail?

Comment: Refer this link it will be use full for your doubt. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model

Comment: Thanks very much ashokramcse.  This helped clear things up a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't really work explicity with Object relation ships of is, has a. You don't have scope modifiers like private, protected, public, although there are several methods to mimic these kinds of behaviors. Objects can still inherit from each other, and you can create aggregation's. But this isn't quite the same syntax as in java, also everything is in Object in javascript and it's weakly typed. It isn't quite the same for some things but you can simulate this. Cheers.

Comment: Not everything is public in javascript.

Comment: Oh would you mind giving me an example :) ? It's a chance to learn then for me.

Comment: Declaring vars within functions or within control flow statements make them private. [Here](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) is a detailed description.

Comment: There is this thing called **closure**  through which you can achieve private and public. Go through this [tutorial](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/) you might get an idea

Comment: I already know that jokers -.-'. But that is referring to implicit scope management.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has prototypical relationships, which are similar, but subtly different from class relationships in Java.

An object can still inherit from another object and there is no reason why could not view objects in terms of has-a and is-a relationships.

The differences between the two object models come down to how the relationships are defined and the flexibility (which is not necessarily a good thing) that JavaScript offers in terms of adding functions after class definition.